# Help identify unknown language

Tags: written-language

Got this $5 bill stamped with a message in a language I cannot identify.

[image: note]

Answer (score 9):

It's a Buddhist mantra [*Om mani padme hum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_mani_padme_hum) in Sanskrit written in the Tibetan script.

Comment: Funny to note how hard to learn Tibetan ligatures (དྨ) may be :)